# How to invoke a Lambda function (Node)?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have been going through [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-lambda-function-prep.html) on writing Lambda functions using Node.

I don't find the ARN of the Lambda function being used or mentioned at all. How does the invoking code uniquely reference the Lambda function?

The Lambda function has the following signature:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => { }
```

In the example on that page, no parameters were used in the invocation. If I need to pass parameters, how do I do so?

Comment: The page you linked is about *creating* a Lambda function, not *invoking* (running) one, and the function prototype is essentially abstracted away at the Lambda Invoke API, so of minimal interest to the caller.  A Lambda function doesn't really need to know its own ARN... it can discover it in `context.invokedFunctionArn` -- though I don't think that is relevant to what you are actually trying to work through at the moment.  What environment are you trying to invoke the function from?  Is the caller using Node.js, or aws-cli, or ...?  You can also test-invoke directly from the Lambda console.

Comment: One of the pages, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/browser-invoke-lambda-function-example.html, has an example of invoking the lambda. I see a `pullparams` with a `FunctionName` property. Not sure if `FunctionName` is the lambda identifier. Given a Lambda ARN, how do I call it from another Node script.